# Why need to write the type variable that get the object of a custom class?

Tags: java

I dont understand why is that

for example:

```
class Test
{
   public void someMethod()
   {



   }

}
```

and then

```
Test test = new Test();
```

why is neccesary to write the type of the variable, so if you see that the variable assigns that custom class, i think that is some overflow writing).

ps: this is java, and i am new to it, so sorry if a quiestion is stupid, but i dont understand this moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the type of the variable (reference), as distinct to the type of the object.

e.g. your variable type could be `Test`, or it could be a supertype (`Object`), or an interface that `Test` implements. Which one you choose depends on how your clients should refer to the initialised object. e.g. should they know it's a particular type, or is it sufficent (or desirable) that they only know it will implement a given interface, or subset of features.

A better example would be:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
```

in which your client code only knows that it's dealing with an Animal. i.e. it can (say) call a method `.eat()`, but it won't know that a `Dog` eats differently to a `Fish`.

Note that some languages (e.g. Scala) will perform *type inference*. That is, you don't have to declare the variable type, but rather the compiler will determine what type it should be from your subsequent usage of the variable. The resultant code is still statically typed, but the compiler does more work for you.

Comment: +1, that's true but I think an `auto` keyword like in C++ and `var` in C# will be good in `Java`.

Comment: If you look at Scala you'll see that it provides such a facility. e.g. val animal = new Dog

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one of declaring the variable and creating an instance of the variable. The first `Test` declares the variable. You can do this without creating an instance by doing:

```
Test test;
```

The second `Test` in `new Test()` calls the constructor for the variable. In this case since you didn't create a constructor you are using the default `Object` constructor. This can be done with a previously defined variable as in:

```
Test test;
test = new Test();
```

Also you can have multiple constructors that take different parameters and then you have to specify which you want to use.

```
public class Test {

    public Test(int i) {
    }

    public Test() {
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Test test = new Test();
Test test2 = new Test(2);
```